# Lost Connection to "iPhone"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web-services

When i am trying to run application in the real device getting this error

**Restore the connection to “iPhone” and run “My App” again, or if “My App” is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > My App.**

Actually getting this problem when loading bunch of images(nearly 35) into CollectionView from web service.

But not getting this problem when i am running in simulator.

Comment: Did the phone become unplugged from the computer? or did the lock screen come on?

Comment: it is plugged only and i tested in three different real devices and got same problem

Comment: Yo may have created production certificate instead of development certificate. The process debugger fails to attach the process in that case.

Comment: I have developer certificate also, if your right then why i did not get this problem for other applications and getting this problem only when loading images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a memory issue if you have images of very high resolution. Check the memory usage of the device in Xcode `Debug Navigator`.

To debug if it is because of images

- Try using no images or disable image loading in the code and check if the problem still persists

If it is because of high memory allocation you might have to resize the images.

Comment: Ya using high resolution images only. Ok let me try with low resolution images.

Comment: hey I am having same issue as I am loading the high resolution images so is there any way to handle the memory issue with these images? thanks:)

Comment: You'll have to reduce the size of the images. Try loading less resolution ones

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode Menu select Debug => Attach to process => Select iOS Simulator

[image]

IT works for me :)
or you can quit xcode and restart again