# Xcode lost connection to iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I know there are already some posts here talking about the same problem, which is, when run the app on device, `Xcode` shows `Xcode lost connection to iPhone, Restore the connection to App....`, But my situation is a bit strange.

My app works perfectly on my `iPhone 6S ( iOS 10.1 Beta 3 )` but on my iPhone 6 Plus ( iOS 10.0.2 ), the app will `crash` and `Xcode` shows that information. I read some posts here saying it might be because my app loads too many high resolution photos and the OS kill the process due to high memory use [Lost Connection to "iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250978/lost-connection-to-iphone), but what happened to me let me think -- Could it be a `iOS` issue??? Since on `iOS 10.1 Beta 3` it has no problems. ( And when `iOS 9`, no problems as well )

This really bothers me and if it is really an OS issue, then how to solve this? how do those big companies'app ( like Facebook ) avoid the OS issues when there is a new `iOS` version released ? I mean, the generally users don't have Beta version.

will be very appreciated if any answer or advice.

Comment: Is it working perfect in simulator of 6plus or any other devices?

Comment: @KAR , it works perfect on simulator as well. but my Xcode is 8.1 Beta, so not sure this will affect the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure that you are not loosing `physical connection`. I means make sure that your `usb cable` is not breaking connection. If it is so then you gots exactly this error which you have mentioned in your question.

Second thing yes this issue can be produce because of large memory consumption (usually large images), in this case you have to resize images to display in your `imageViews` and you should use `less memory`. You should avoid to convert your image to `NSData` if it is not hardly needed. This shouldn't be a bug of `latest ios` but it should be your mistake somewhere to deal with `data`!

Comment: i am sure the usb cable is ok. so i will try the second approach. thx :)