# Add 9 imageview in each tableviewCell by swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, tableview

I try to do customized tableviewCell with imageView in my chat app.
And I need to do 3x3 grid images in each cell.
I face a problem that the imageView memory problem.
How to solve the cell contain 9 imageviews in each cell to prevent memory increase.
Or any good idea to solve it.
I need to decrease memory.
Thanks.

This is my code:

```
case .group:
        var drawSequence:[Int] = [Int]()
        var drawIcons:[String] = [String]()

        let string:String = chatroom.users
        let tempArr = string.components(separatedBy: ",")
        var stringArr = Array<String>()

        for a in tempArr {

            var b = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
            b = b.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
            b = b.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
            stringArr.append(b)
        }

        stringArr.forEach({ (id) in
            drawIcons.append(id)
        })

        let g:CGFloat = 1
        var x:CGFloat = g
        var y:CGFloat = g
        var w:CGFloat = (defaultBigIconWidth - g)/3 - g
        switch drawIcons.count {
        case let count where count >= 9:
            drawSequence = [3,3,3]
            break
        case 8:
            drawSequence = [2,3,3]
            break
        case 7:
            drawSequence = [1,3,3]
            break
        case 6:
            drawSequence = [3,3]
            y = defaultBigIconWidth/2-w
            break
        case 5:
            drawSequence = [2,3]
            y = defaultBigIconWidth/2-w
            break
        case 4:
            w = (defaultBigIconWidth - g)/2 - g
            drawSequence = [2,2]
            y = defaultBigIconWidth/2-w
            break
        case 3:
            w = (defaultBigIconWidth - g)/2 - g
            drawSequence = [1,2]
            y = defaultBigIconWidth/2-w
            break
        case 2:
            w = (defaultBigIconWidth - g)/2 - g
            drawSequence = [2]
            y = (defaultBigIconWidth-w)/2
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        for row in drawSequence {
            switch row {
            case 1:
                x = (defaultBigIconWidth-w)/2
                break
            case 2:
                x = defaultBigIconWidth/2-w
                break
            default:
                x = g
                break
            }
            for _ in 0..<row {
                let id = drawIcons.removeFirst()
                let ui:UIImageView = GeneratorAvatarImageView()
                ui.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: w)
                icon.addSubview(ui)

                if id == currentUser.id {
                    user = contacts[currentUser.id]
                    ImageFromUrl(imageView: ui, url: (user?.avatar)!, type: "user")
                }else{
                    user = contacts[id]
                    ImageFromUrl(imageView: ui, url: (user?.avatar)!, type: "user")
                }
                x += w+g
            }
            y += w+g
        }
        break
```

```
func ImageFromUrl(imageView:UIImageView,url:String,type:String) {

if url.isEmpty {
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultIcon")
    print("Url is empty.")
    return
}

var documentsDirectoryURL:URL

if type == "user" {

    documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("Image/User/")

    let exist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path)

    if !exist {

        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debug(object: error)
        }
    }

}

// create a name for your image
let fileName = url.md5()
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
let urlString = URL(string: url)

if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path) {
    imageView.image = image
    return
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: urlString!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    if data != nil
    {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {

                var c = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 1)
                (data! as NSData).getBytes(&c, length: 1)
                switch (c[0]) {
                case 0xFF:
                    print("Download jpg: \(url)")
                    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {

                        do {
                            try jpegData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            debug(object: error)
                        }
                    }
                case 0x89:
                    print("Download png: \(url)")
                    if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                        do {
                            try pngData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            debug(object: error)
                        }
                    }
                case 0x47:
                    print("Download gif: \(url)")
                default:
                    print("Download unknown: \(c[0])\(url)")
                }

            } else {
                //                    debug(object:"file already exists")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
}

func GeneratorAvatarImageView() -> UIImageView {

let imageview = UIImageView()
imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 2
imageview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
return imageview
}
```

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: What is your problem extractly? A freezing UI or memory? I don't think 9 images on a cell is a big problem with memory

Comment: Because I happen this situation, and then I think the image have much memory usage.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250978/lost-connection-to-iphone

Comment: I show have some loop in your code and it maybe the reason for your problem. Can you show me `ImageFromUrl ` method?

Comment: @trungduc I update the method.

Comment: And how about `GeneratorAvatarImageView` method?

Comment: Try to put the code which gets image on background queue and only back to main queue when you had image to use.

Comment: it's just setting of imageview.  I update.

Comment: I have added an answer, please take a look.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: What is the size of an imageView?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is add a **UICollectionView** to your cell, it will be better than add 9 ImageViews to your cell. and I've tried this method, it will not cause memory problems.

Explanation:
I think the images on **UICollectionView** that you added to your cell can be reused, although it add more views on your cell but it has cell reused function. so it will not cause memory problems.

Hope that it can solve your problem.

Comment: Add collectionView why be better than imageViews.

Comment: Actually, it won't be better for sure.

Comment: oh. it's so complex to me. Have any explain?

Comment: It can't be better. Adding `collectionView` means that you will add more views to you cell, more logic to your cell. Memory will increase instead of decreasing.

Comment: I've update my answer, I think ImageViews on UICollectionView's cell can be reused, so it will not cause memory problems.

Comment: For me. I've tried this way on my own project. and it does work for me.

Comment: ImageViews on UITableViewCell can be reused too, so i think it's hard to resolve problem with UICollectionViewCell inside UITableViewCell

Comment: But the difference is: every image is a cell in UICollectionView, another is 9 images on a UITableView is a cell. so that's difference.

Comment: By the way. I think the solution i offered is not the main problem of his code, maybe images cache is the point

Comment: Agree. I think loops for loading image can be the reason for his issue.

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx this will work fine and even your code work will be optimized. Your screen will be dynamic as per the number of images. Cell will be automatically manage your memory as if collectioncell is disappeared from the screen then its memory will be released. It can be complex but its not too hard such that you can not achieve this. **Take ref->** https://medium.com/@adinugroho/fixed-height-uicollectionview-inside-uitableview-79f24657d08f