# How to convert CMSampleBuffer to Data for video in Swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, cmsamplebuffer

I have downloaded a source code from [here](https://navoshta.com/metal-camera-bonus-running-simulator/). I am getting `CMSampleBuffer` for video from the camera in the following function.

```
public func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        do {
            var textures: [MTLTexture]!

            switch pixelFormat {
            case .rgb:
                let textureRGB = try texture(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, textureCache: textureCache)
                textures = [textureRGB]
            case .yCbCr:
                let textureY = try texture(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, textureCache: textureCache, planeIndex: 0, pixelFormat: .r8Unorm)
                let textureCbCr = try texture(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, textureCache: textureCache, planeIndex: 1, pixelFormat: .rg8Unorm)
                textures = [textureY, textureCbCr]
            }

            let timestamp = try self.timestamp(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)

            delegate?.metalCameraSession(self, didReceiveFrameAsTextures: textures, withTimestamp: timestamp)

        }
        catch let error as MetalCameraSessionError {
            self.handleError(error)
        }
        catch {
            /**
             * We only throw `MetalCameraSessionError` errors.
             */
        }
    }
```

> How can I convert `sampleBuffer` to `Data` using `Swift` 4?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054779/how-to-convert-cmsamplebuffer-to-data-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But it is creating another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250978/lost-connection-to-iphone?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) instead with iPhone not simulator.